# Is $f: (0,\pi/2)\to [0,1]^2/ f(x)=(\cos x, \sin x) $ injective?

Tags: functions

Is $f: (0,\pi/2)\to [0,1]^2/ f(x)=(\cos x, \sin x) $ injective?

I set $f(x)=f(y)\implies $ $\cos x=\cos y$ and $\sin x=\sin y$. So applying the inverse function to both should result in $x=y$, but I'm not sure if I should add a $+2\pi n$ somewhere...

Comment: why would you want to add $2\pi$?

Comment: Because $cos(0)=cos(2\pi)$ for example (although that would take the argument outside the domain, but I'm not sure).

Comment: Do not add a $2\pi$. Think carefully about it, there is no reason to.

Comment: exactly. neither $0$ nor $2\pi$ is inside the domain.

Comment: observe also that the range is just the unit circle that lies within the first quadrant

Comment: And in fact the inverse of $f$ exists, which is the [atan2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that $f_1'(x) = -\sin x < 0, f_2'(x) = \cos x > 0$. This means both component of $f'(x)$ are monotone functions, thus $f$ is injective.